# iPad form creation?

Tags: iphone, forms, ipad, uitableview, uitextfield

I would like to create a form in my iPad application which is very similar to the form used when setting up the Cellular Data Account on the iPad.

That is, it collects User Information, Payment information, and other information from the user in a modal view across multiple steps.

Is there a good tutorial out there for creating this type of interface? It looks like it makes use of a tableview with embedded UITextInputs in the editable cells.

Creating this kind of interface is trivial in HTML. Hopefully it is equally easy on the iPad.

Thanks in advance for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Its not as trivial as HTML, but there are a few tutorials that when combined should point you on the way: [Editable UITextFields in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell), and then for the modal view part, you could have a UINavigationController presented modally, and then push/pop UITableViewControllers as you wished.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and the link.