# Only addSubView in certain cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, cell

I have 10 cells/rows in a UITableView and I have set four of these cells to have some text like so:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Before School";
    }
```

I'm doing all of this inside:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I am trying to add a UITextField to only specific rows. How can I achieve this? I have managed to add a UITextField to either all or none of them using:

```
[cell addSubview:textField];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `if else` statements. For example:

```
if([indexPath row] == 0){
  [cell setAccessoryView:textField];
}else if([indexPath row] == 1){
  [cell setAccessoryView:textField];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The process would be the same as setting the cell's `textLabel.text` property:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    [cell addSubview:textField];
}
```

Other examples:

Adds a UITextView to all even rows:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
{
    [cell addSubview:textField];
}
```

See this SO post for more code: [Having a UITextField in a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell)