# Customizing UINavigationController's Edit button?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

How do I draw "save" & "cancel" buttons on the navigation bar when the user taps "edit"? Also, how do I hide the delete "knobs" and instead make each row editable, like Apple's Contacts app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `UIViewController` has a `-setEditing:animated:` method that you can overwrite. In this method you could call `-setRightBarButtonItem` or `-setLeftBarButtonItem`.

As for your second question, take a look at the `UITableViewDataSource`. There's a method called `-tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath`.

EDIT: If you want to enter text in a `UITableViewCell`, you have to place a `UITextField` inside it in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell).

Comment: Glad I could help. Please use the tick to mark it as the correct answer, so that others can see it too.

Comment: hello! i've posted a new question separately but to keep it in context ive added it here as well. could you please have a  look below to see if you could help

Answer (score 3):

To create a `Cancel` button on the left side, implement the `setEditing:animated:` method and put the following inside.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelEdit:)] autorelease];
```

And to add a `Save` button:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(SaveEdit:)] autorelease];
```

Make sure you implement `cancelEdit:` and `saveEdit:`.

Comment: Both answers helped me equally. But I got kind of lost in the other answer. I think this should be the ticked answer. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

To both answers, I should add the following:

To remove added button, set the `right/leftBarButtonItem` to `nil`