# how to make text field in tableview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I want to know how to make text field in tableview in iphone.

it means how to add uitextfield on uiTableviewCell and How handle it?

In order to handle means respond to it delegate and fetching value at the time of submission....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];
textField.tag = 1000;
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
[textField release];
```

In customization part,

```
UITextField *textField = [[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1000];
textField.text = @"Your text";
```

Comment: is possible to add multiple textfield here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621732/how-to-add-textfield-in-tableview-cell-and-access-each-textfields-text-by-their

Answer (score 2):

Find the below link

[Having a UITextField in a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell)
or try this one

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if( cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];   

    cell.textLabel.text = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First",@"Second",@"Third",@"Forth",@"Fifth",@"Sixth",@"Seventh",@"Eighth",@"Nineth",@"Tenth",nil] 
                           objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21)];
        textField.placeholder = @"Enter Text";
        textField.text = [inputTexts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2];
        textField.tag = indexPath.row/2;
        textField.delegate = self;
        cell.accessoryView = textField;
        [textField release];
    } else
        cell.accessoryView = nil;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tryout this code in `CellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
UITextField *textField = [UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
cell.contentView =textField;
[textField release];
```

Comment: @Nitin he is write if u just want to add textfield in tableview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621732/how-to-add-textfield-in-tableview-cell-and-access-each-textfields-text-by-their

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance of either UITextView Or UTextField  and add it into the UITableViewCell as sub view.