# Textfield in appearing multiple times UItableViewGrouped

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uitableview

I found some example code of how to implement a textfield into a cell here:
[Having a UITextField in a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell)

However the textfield appears multiple times on my table in the 1st section of the table, even though i specified it to only appear when it comes up to the 2nd section of the table and the first row of that section.

Any explanations why this happens? I only want it in the 2nd section 1 st row. but it appears to think that whenever the 2nd section is coming up it will just draw the textfield in advance. Is there a way to "lock" it to a particular group and cell?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [self CreateMultilinesCell:CellIdentifier];
}
NSLog(@"%d", [indexPath section]);
if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
    NSLog(@"TextField");

    if ([indexPath row] == 0 ) {
        UITextField *replyTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 185, 30)];
        replyTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        replyTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        replyTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        replyTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        replyTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        replyTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; 
        replyTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        replyTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        replyTextField.tag = 0;
        replyTextField.delegate = self;

        replyTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
        [replyTextField setEnabled: YES];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:replyTextField];

        [replyTextField release];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"something";

    }
}
else {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [separatedString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
}
```

createmultilinecell:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) CreateMultilinesCell :(NSString*)cellIdentifier
{
//NSLog(@"Entering CreateMultilinesCell");
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                                reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.detailTextLabel.font = [self SubFont];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255 green:10.0/255 blue:33.0/255 alpha:1.0];
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];//]colorWithRed:.98 green:.98 blue:.99 alpha:1.0]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];//colorWithRed:.94 green:.96 blue:.99 alpha:1.0]];
                                                         //NSLog(@"Exiting CreateMultilinesCell");
return cell;
}
```

argh i'm too low to answer my own question so i'll just update here:

Looks like making 2 cellidentifiers work. Thanks. Just learnt something new! haha.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSString *replyCellIdentifier = @"replyCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UITextField *replyTextField;
if (cell == nil) {
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        cell = [self CreateMultilinesCell:CellIdentifier];      
    }
    else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"TextField");
        cell = [self CreateMultilinesCell:replyCellIdentifier];     
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            replyTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 185, 30)];
            replyTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            replyTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            replyTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            replyTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            replyTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            replyTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; 
            replyTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
            replyTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            replyTextField.tag = 0;
            replyTextField.delegate = self;

            replyTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
            [replyTextField setEnabled: YES];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:replyTextField];

            [replyTextField release];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"something";
        }           
    }
    /*else {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [separatedString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }*/
}
NSLog(@"%d", [indexPath section]);
if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [separatedString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
return cell;
}
```

thanks to everyone that contributed.

In terms of functionality i'm not so sure yet but it's one step closer to getting where i want it to be :).

Comment: Possibly because you're reusing the cell.

Comment: Post the code used in  [self CreateMultilinesCell:CellIdentifier], i think problem lies there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try having two different cells, one with a textField and one without. Use different `CellIdentifier` strings for the two different types of cells. That should resolve it.

Comment: Yes. Using two different cells in this case is better than adding extra code/burden to remove the text field from the `cell.contentView` and adding it again in a particular cell, whenever the cell is resused.

Comment: Different problem (cell appearing multiple times during scrolling), solved using 2 different cell identifiers. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you have this part of your code outside the `if(cell == nil)`

```
if ([indexPath row] == 0 ) {
    UITextField *replyTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 185, 30)];
    ...........

}
```

So this line of code is always called when you scroll the table view to see that row and thus adding uitextfield every time, so what you can do

Declare that variable in this block `if(cell == nil){....}`

Also if you are not adding or deleting any rows or section in your table view than it will work just fine.

**PS.**It is alot harder to handle tableview when you are using it to show dynamic data that user can edit.

You will have to do more than that but for now I think you are good to get started.

Comment: thanks robin i'm working on it now and will update once I get it working.

Answer (score -1):

Try this if your using section

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row]
```

and if you are not using section then use

`NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%i",indexPath.row]`;

Comment: This will create individual cell for each and every row in the table, which will possibly increase the memory and may slow down while scrolling the table view