# Where to find a form like control for iPhone

Tags: iphone, forms

You know how on the iPhone one can go to settings> mail > add account > gmail > fillable form

What is the name of that fillable form control? I want to use it in my app but can't find it in Interface Builder. Or rather what is the approach for putting it together using other components?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to build your form from the elements provided in IB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ittybittydude/IBAForms

you can quickly make forms using the built-in form field types or create your own custom fields and the user interfaces used to enter data for them.

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! That promises to be a very good pointer, I'll try it out. But another search (following your idea of searching on github) led to a project called: https://github.com/elc/ELCTextFieldCell which does similar work as well. You wouldn't happen to have any strong opinions on which one of the two, folks should use and why ... would you? Or should I start a separate thread if I want that answered :) One thing that is utterly obvious is the better readme for IBAForms but then ELCTextFieldCell has more "watchers"...

Comment: Nvm, I gather that ELCTextFieldCell is really just focused on a label and a text field, nothing more so IBAForms is much more versatile. Too bad its only 4.0 or above only at this point http://groups.google.com/group/ibaforms/browse_thread/thread/8923794083a07cf9

Answer (score 2):

It's a `UITableView`. Create your own `UITableViewCell` subclass with a `UITextField` in it and use the cells for the table view.

You might want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell).