# GroupedTableView in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

i want to create a grouptableview for my application in which some section are editable and some are checkedmark can any body tell me in details to how i do this ,
i want to put content in row like 'placeholder in textbox'.

I have tried many times and search in google bt i m nt getting any idea please help to out this issues.
i want to create grouptableview like this image for my application.

[!Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx4V2.png)

Comment: Did your Google searching throw up the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)? That should give you a few ideas to start with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want **to edit the content of cell**, you have to add *UITextField/UITextView* to the cell. You can very well assign a *placeHolder* for the *UITextField/UITextView*. [Refer this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell).

For **check mark** you can use default cell by toggling its *accessoryType* between *UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark* and *UITableViewCellAccessoryNone*.

Answer (score 0):

based on your noofsections you can create the no of groups.