# Text Field on Top of Button - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

So I'm trying to figure out ideas for my registration page in xCode -- something like this: http://weswilliams.me/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/IMG_2525-e1307910945329.png

At any rate, I can't figure out what objects they are using to achieve this display. It looks like a TextField on top of a Button? If it is, I can never get the Text Field to sit on top, it always falls behind the button, thus making it invisible.

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a textfield on the button. Actually it is text box inside a table view. You have to do the following :

1. Take a table view on the nib.
2. Create the outlet and set the delegate and datasource.
3. Then add the following code to your .m file.

try this one

before this set the number of rows the table view has.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if( cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];   

    cell.textLabel.text = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First",@"Second",@"Third",@"Forth",@"Fifth",@"Sixth",@"Seventh",@"Eighth",@"Nineth",@"Tenth",nil] 
                           objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21)];
        textField.placeholder = @"Enter Text";
        textField.text = [inputTexts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2];
        textField.tag = indexPath.row/2;
        textField.delegate = self;
        cell.accessoryView = textField;
        [textField release];
    } else
        cell.accessoryView = nil;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;        
}
```

Or you can see this link [See this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 0):

Thats a basic grouped UITableView.  Read up on Apple docs.  There are a ton of tutorials on that too.