# UITableView inside UIView not working as expected with UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

Ok guys so here's the problem. I'm loading a UITableView inside a UIView and it's not displaying the two textfields:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate> {

    UITableView *loginTableView;
    UITextField *username;
    UITextField *password;

}

@property UITableView *loginTableView;
@property UITextField *username;
@property UITextField *password;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize loginTableView, username, password;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Make rounded corners view
    [self.view.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
    [self.view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    self.view.layer.opaque = NO;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Add login table view to main view
    loginTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    loginTableView.delegate = self;
    loginTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:loginTableView];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 2;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if( cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 280, 21)];
        username.placeholder = @"Username";
        username.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [username setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        cell.accessoryView = username;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 280, 21)];
        password.placeholder = @"Password";
        password.secureTextEntry = YES;
        password.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [password setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
       cell.accessoryView = password;
    }

    username.delegate = self;
    password.delegate = self;

    [loginTableView addSubview:username];
    [loginTableView addSubview:password];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;

}

@end
```

Anyone could please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it just covering up the text fields? I don't see where you ever set the size of the table view.

Comment: I've just edited what you've said and it's not working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're adding the textfields to the tableview and not the actual cell

```
[loginTableView addSubview:username]; //you're saying to add it to the table
```

Also, you're adding the `username` twice

EDIT:

[You may want to check out this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Yep! I'm aware of that. Is that wrong? I've just edited what you've said about the repetition error and it's not working yet.

Comment: so that function you're working in draws each table cell when the table is rendered and then adds the cell to the table itself (very high level explanation) .. you can see that that function returns a `UITableViewCell`, so in order to add those views, you must add them to the cell and not the table.  I'll open up a project i have in a few and get the exact line you need

Comment: I edited my answer to contain a link to another SO question that I used to implement a login feature using a tableview.  If you're not trying to create a login, that'll help you too because it adds the subview to the cell

Comment: I tried your code but I just got an empty tableView without the textfields not quite the image you're showing in your post. I love to have that.

Comment: I think you're missing `loginTableView.delegate = self` and `loginTableView.datasource = self` in your view did load.  Can you set breakpoints to see if that function is being called?

Comment: Also, add those lines of code before you add the tableview to your uiview and after you initialize your tableview

Comment: Ok AngeloS i got it working thanks to your advise! THANK YOU! Now it's just that it crashes when I try to add the email or password.