# Using tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: to edit a UITextField in a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

How would you use `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` to trigger `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`: ?

Or what other options do I have? I did consider having `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`: trigger a UIAlertView (with textField) but it isn't aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Check out - http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/03/13/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xibs-step-by-step-tutorial/ and http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-create-simple-tableview-with-custom-cells

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little light on details: what's the user interface look like? What are you tying to accomplish?

To literally answer your question, you can just have didDeselectRowAtIndexPath implementation call the method textFieldShouldBeginEditing - however I don't believe that's what you're asking? What it sounds like you're asking is how you can get a touch event on a table view cell to pass into a UITextField so that editing begins.

That would make this a duplicate of other questions already asked here:
[Having a UITextField in a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how proper the practice is, but I have an app I use a textField that is 1x1 points and off screen. If I want to bring up the keyboard, I call

```
[self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Then you can use the UITextFieldDelegate methods to control and update information being entered on the keyboard.

Then when the user is done, I call

```
[self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Of course this is assuming that you don't actually want to use a textField in your tableView.

Hope this helps.