# UITextField Set Border

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to make my login interface a little bit more fancy. So I wanted to build somethin like this:

[image]

Thats what i Have to far:

```
    self.usernameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.usernameTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
self.usernameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
self.usernameTextField.clipsToBounds      = YES;

    self.passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
self.passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:171.0/255.0 green:171.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
self.passwordTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
self.passwordTextField.clipsToBounds      = YES;
```

How can I connect them? There is still a gap between the two UITextFields..

Comment: your problem is that you have the corner to every angle of your textFiled

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a `UITableView` with rounded corners?

Comment: I guess it's a tableview

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having a UITextField in a UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: @MarcJohnson: Just fix this image in imageView. And create two textField with no border. And fix the text field in correct position in imageview. Then customize the image with no text instead of text in imageview. you show the text (Email) as place holder

Comment: You could also use `UIRectCorner` to create a path to mask around the views...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put plain image background like your interface and put two text fields on that image and set boarder style like below.

```
[yourTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

Comment: you can set the UITextField to Boarder Style None in Story board. Then I was able to change the height and added the image!

Answer (score 0):

The example you show is almost certainly using a table view. If you want to mimic it created a grouped table view with 2 static rows and add your text fields to each row. Make sure the text fields border style is set to none (it should be the default in IB), then set your placeholder text and color. If you want the icons, that is probably just a small UIImageView to the left of the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your UITextField border style to none.

```
[self.textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

and then use custom background images, to get the desired look.

Answer (score 0):

Create your both TextField custom type. Dont set any border style.. Fix the image in ImageView and then place the two text field frame for the text in imageview.