# How can I set two UITextFields together with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to put two `UITextFields` with `Swift` together similar to this question: [UITextField Set Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635872/uitextfield-set-border).

So the result should be one `UITextField` above the other and they will collapse on the border-bottom of the first one.

I am following the code that is on the question related:

```
tfUser.layer.borderWidth = 1
tfUser.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 69/255, green: 106/255, blue: 153/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
tfUser.layer.cornerRadius = 5
tfUser.clipsToBounds = true; //I am not able to equal this property to 'YES' so I put 'true'. Looking on the documentation I could see that it only accepts a boolean value.

tfPassword.layer.borderWidth = 2
tfPassword.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 69/255, green: 106/255, blue: 153/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
tfPassword.layer.cornerRadius = 5
tfPassword.clipsToBounds = true; //I am not able to equal this property to 'YES' so I put 'true'. Looking on the documentation I could see that it only accepts a boolean value.
```

I also have tried with the accepted answer but it does not recognize that property (I tried with `borderStyle` but it also does not work as I cannot set it to `UITextBorderStyleNone`).

The result I am getting right now is:

[image]

Am I missing something? What can I do to put them together?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why any reason but it also does not work as I cannot set it to UITextBorderStyleNone

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I am sorry but I do not understand what do you want to say.

Comment: sorry bro - why you can't set the UITextBorderStyleNone is there any reason

Comment: I think you didn't get accepted answer of reference link. You don't need to set any border to your text field. you create and image with this border, Put it in your view and above it put your text field

Comment: Create a `UIView` that contains `tfUser` and `tfPassword`, giving the border and corner radius you want to the UIView.

Comment: @Error404 - oh , your problem is solved or you need the support for this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I am going to try it now (I did not have a mac since I put the question). As fast I try it I will accept your answer if it works :)

Comment: @Error404 - sure bro, I added the sample project also , check once it will helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your concept

**step-1**

Create One UIView and add the two textfield subview of UIVIew.

**Step-2**

set your   `yourTextField.borderStyle` as `None` and set border width and border color

**step-3**

set the corner radius of UIView as `UIView.layer.cornerRadius = 5`

**updated answer**

you can downloaded the sample project in [**here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xux7ajql5szoh59/test.zip?dl=0)

create one UIVIew, and two textfields and set your `yourTextField.borderStyle = .None`

```
  @IBOutlet weak var backview: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var txtpassword: UITextField!
```

and called in your page like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.changecornerRadius(self.txtpassword)
  self.changecornerRadius(self.txtUserName)
self.changecornerRadiussd(self.backview)
}



func  changecornerRadius(textfield: UITextField)  {
    textfield.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
    textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    textfield.clipsToBounds = true
     let paddingView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
    textfield.leftView=paddingView;
    textfield.leftViewMode = .Always
}

func  changecornerRadiussd(currentView: UIView)  {
    currentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    currentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    currentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    currentView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

you get the output as

[image]

Comment: see this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640488/how-do-i-create-connected-text-fields-in-ios

Comment: Choice 2 does not produce the same result as shown in the link OP mentioned. You may still have to work on setting the cornerRadius

Comment: Ok. I have tried with your code and it gives to me a space between two `UITextFields` and also another space between the second `UITextField`. I also downloaded your project and I saw that you do not have anything on your visual interface on your `Main.storyboard`. Are you declaring them in another file? I am totally new so I think I am missing something basic concept.

Comment: @Error404 - no no I added the textfield in ViewController, Its available in `Main.storyboard` if it is not visible change the background color of View Contrller and check once

Comment: I have changed background color to the TextView and a text to see if on `Main.storyboard` (on ViewController) it is changed but I cannot see any effect on the visual interface (I can see the changes only if I run the code). But I noticed that it is declared in the tree that is on the left of the `Main.storyboard`.  In your example, in mine I cannot figure out what could be the problem because the code to do this `UIView` is the same.

Comment: @Error404 - I added the background color everything in the code ,

Comment: I could get both `UITextView` together but adjusting them visually, not programatically. It is why I wanted to see how they were adjusted on your visual interface but I could not see them neither with background.

Comment: @Error404 - shall I delete my answer if it is not useful

Comment: I do not think that is not useful at all because if I execute your project it works like a charm. Just I am not able to detect what are the differences between my project and yours and finally I adapted it visually instead of programatically. I will accept your answer because I think it is the most relevant of all the answers here (and helped the fact that I did not know about UIView).

Comment: @Error404 - sure bro , if you need the support related to this I will help

Answer (score 0):

To set UITextBorderStyleNone in Swift:

```
yourTextField.borderStyle = .None
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 3 solutions and both use `UITextBorderStyleNon‌e`:

1. add 2 background image
2. make grouped `UITableView`, cells should contain `UITextFields`
3. Draw it in frameRect method

I recommend to use number two

Answer (score 0):

the best way to achieve this ..have a look below code

```
@IBAction func showLoginPasswordAlert(sender: UIButton) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "User login", message: "login password ..!!", preferredStyle:
        UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(configurationTextFieldLogin)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(configurationTextFieldPassword)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Ok button")
//            print(self.textField.text)
    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
}
```

---

```
// func to add login textfield
func configurationTextFieldLogin(textField: UITextField!)
{
    if let aTextField = textField {
        textField.text = "Login"
    }
}
```

---

```
// function to add password textfield
func configurationTextFieldPassword(textField: UITextField!)
{
    if let aTextField = textField {
        textField.text = "Password"
    }
}
```

or you can edit in your best way..